# Codeigniter __construct being called multiple times in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've the following controller class in my codeigniter and I want to load my `library` and `model` in constructor so that I can use it throughout my class.

```
class Cities extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct()
{
    echo "a";
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("cities");
    $this->load->model("model_city");       
}


public function getCities($type)
{
            echo "ab";
    if($type == "All" || $type == "*" )
    {
        $res = $this->model_city->getCities();
    }
    else
    {
        $res = $this->model_city->getPopularCities();
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    }
    var_dump($res->results());
}
}
```

When I visit the URL , this code echoes `"a"` several times and doesn't call the `getCities` function. Here's the url I am visiting.

```
http://localhost/teleprintblog/index.php/Cities/getCities/All
```

What is the problem here ? Why is it calling the `constructor` again and again without calling the `getCities` function ?

Comment: This is an interesting one. Also, why are you calling this? $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you cant give a same name to a Controller and library class.

Here it is calling the controller class again and again thats why it is calling the controller again and again.

Comment: I'm in the beginning phase of learning CI. Could you please elaborate on this? Shouldn't the php filename and class name be the same? Nvm..figured it out. Somehow missed the word "library"

Comment: yes you are right, but what I am trying to say is:
if you create a Controller class named "Cities" in application/Controllers, then you cant create library class with same name as "Cities". you have to keep the class names different

Comment: Yeh, thanks. Like I said, I overlooked that you were referring to a "library" and not the filename